# $1+1=0$ What am I doing wrong???!

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fake-proofs

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm struggling with this for a while now and I don't see what I do wrong!

$$1+1=$$
$$1+\sqrt{1}=$$
$$1+\sqrt{-1*-1}=$$
$$1+\sqrt{-1}*\sqrt{-1}=$$
$$1+i*i=$$
$$1-1=0$$

Comment: The third "=" is wrong.

Comment: If you had to figure out where the mistake is, what would you try?  Which step are you the least certain about?  For example, you might try drawing vectors on a complex plane.

Comment: Also $\sqrt{-1}=i$ is wrong. The square root of complex numbers that are not real and nonnegative is not single-valued. (In other words, why do you say that $\sqrt{-1}=i$ instead of $\sqrt{-1}=-i$? How can you choose one of the two?)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: You are wrong. The choice is built into the definition of $i$ and $\sqrt{\cdot}$. The choice does not matter because all field extensions of $\mathbb{R}$ that add a root of the polynomial $x \mapsto x^2+1$ are isomorphic. Also, the only field automorphism of $\mathbb{C}$ that fixes $\mathbb{R}$ is conjugation, which is simply a reflection about the real axis.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\sqrt {ab}=\sqrt {a} .\sqrt b$$ For $a,b\ge 0$

Comment: Lemme guess, you have a proof for this but the answer box is too small to contain it? (couldn't help myself sorry...)

Comment: @SubSevn Take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_fallacy#Power_and_root

Comment: I was making a joke about your last theorem in the margins...

Answer (score 2):

$1+\sqrt{-1\cdot-1}\neq1+\sqrt{-1}\cdot\sqrt{-1}$. That is **the** issue with your "proof" that $1+1=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You've run into a common problem of the square root. It can take on two value. usually we use the principal root, that is to say the positive square root of a number. In this case, you've split the root into two part, however, you can't do that because it could then have 4 combinations of signs, 2 visible combinations. Most of the time this isn't a problem, because splitting two positive roots results in 2 combinations of signs, but only one visible sign.

I should also mention that when you say $1=\sqrt n$, this equality has to hold true even after less than truthful manipulations. If you end up with $-1=1$ its your own fault, because you neglected the original equality.